# What's the meaning of, "Within 3 days of the 1st"?

Tags: meaning

A lease agreement reads, "If rent is not paid within 3 days of the 1st". Does that mean, the 1st + 3 days == the 4th is the final day to pay rent and the 5th day is in breach?

Comment: If you are asking us for a legal interpretation of your lease agreement, please do not do so. Ask your landlord what they mean, or a lawyer if you have one.

Comment: Hi @DJClayworth, I'm not asking for legal advise - just wording on a document I wasn't sure I understood.

Comment: You could certainly argue that the second of the month is within one day of the first, the third is within two days, and the fourth is within three days; but I'm sure that your jurisdiction has a legally established interpretation of that language in a lease, as a point of law—and that's the interpretation that you need to identify, not mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

- "The first" refers to the actual date: the ***1st*** of the month, we presume.
- "Within one day of the first" would mean the ***2nd***.
- "Within two days of the first" would mean the ***3nd***.
- "Within three days of the first" would mean the ***4th***. Last day to pay.
- On the ***5th*** of the month, if still unpaid, the contract would be in breach.

Comment: Thanks - your explanation of the wording through reduction makes it seem so obvious!